# Transform string format to time type in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
time1 = '03 Mar 1999'
time2 = '16 Apr 1999'
```

How to convert the above from string to time?

I need to compare which one is earlier and the time lag(time2-time1)

Comment: i find something useful on https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

Like @Jarvis suggested earlier - you can read the post to get more info.
So you could try  something like this?

```py
    >>> dt1 = datetime.strptime('03 Mar 1999', '%d %b %Y')
    >>> dt1
    datetime.datetime(1999, 3, 3, 0, 0)
    >>> dt2 = datetime.strptime('16 Apr 1999', '%d %b %Y')
    >>> dt2
    datetime.datetime(1999, 4, 16, 0, 0)
    >>> dt2 > dt1
    True
    >>>
```

Answer (score 0):

i find something useful on [Converting Strings to datetime in Python](https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/)

like this

```
import datetime
date_time_str = '16 Oct 2000'
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%d %b %Y')

print('Date:', date_time_obj.date())
```